# Uploading a folder to azure storage using terraform (azurerm_storage_blob) -> Nothing appear when execute plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following resource defined:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "widget_upload" {
   for_each               = fileset("${path.root}/../packages/widget/dist", "**/*")
   name                   = each.key
   storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.main_storage.name
   storage_container_name = "$web"
   type                   = "Block"
   source                 = "${path.root}/../packages/widget/dist/${each.key}"
   content_md5            = filemd5(each.key)
}
```

When I execute

```
terraform plan
```

Nothing appear for this resource.

If I do (with terraform CLI in console mode)

```
❯ terraform console
> fileset("${path.root}/../packages/widget/dist", "**/*")
toset([
  "index.html",
  "v0.0.0/209-88ecfac5fde48cb32584.js",
  "v0.0.0/209-88ecfac5fde48cb32584.js.map",
  "v0.0.0/index-9158507e7eab071ec137.js",
  "v0.0.0/index-9158507e7eab071ec137.js.map",
])
```

We can see the files I am trying to upload ...

What I am missing? Why terraform is not adding the changes to the plan?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found why .... console mode can list file from an upper directory.
But "plan" cannot use "**..**" to access an upper dir.

If you want to do something similar, move the directory you try to upload inside the "terraform workspace".